# Confused about AF, AF-S (Nikon Autofocus)

Tags: autofocus

I have a Nikon D610. I thought it would work with AF lenses, but my Nikkor AF 50 mm 1.8 D doesn't autofocus,
Same for the Yongnuo 50 mm 1.8 AF (the Yongnuo has a MF/AF switch on the lens). 
Are these lenses incompatible with the 610's autofocus, operator error, or...?
AF-S lenses autofocus without difficulty.

Comment: Are you using back-button autofocus (AF-ON)? Is the M/A switch on the camera body set to A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AF lenses use a camera's screw drive motor, which the D610 has. The AF-S lenses use a focus motor that is built into the lens instead.

There is nothing different required settings/control wise to make an AF lens focus compared to an AF-S lens. So I suspect there is a problem with the 610's screw drive and it needs repaired... it might just be stuck in the retracted position.

Comment: Looks like the lens was not seated properly. Didn't think that was possible...

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so with multiple attempts and multiple lenses...

Comment: I took it to a camera shop and they "fixed" it in two seconds. I'm still a little surprised, but the missing info I didn't have was whether or not the 610 supports AF as well as AF-S lenses. So thanks.